# How to create a batch command to make a .zip file name in UTC Time

Tags: batch-file

How can we create a zip file in UTC time or current time (-) minus 3 hours from the existing time.

The command which I use is below pasted:

```
echo on

for /f "tokens=3,2,4 delims=/- " %%x in ("%date%") do set d=%%z%%x_%%y
set date=%d%

for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=:. " %%x in ("%time%") do set t=%%x%%y%%z


set time=%t%

Echo zipping...

"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "C:\DFD\JZR_%d%%t%.zip" "C:\DFD\*.txt"
```

del "C:\DFD*.txt" /s /f /q

echo Done!

if anybody have idea, please help.

Comment: It's [hard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/355425/503046), as batch is pretty limited. Can you use a modern shell, such as Powershell instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off & for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims= " %%a in (`%windir%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -command "& {(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().AddHours(-3).ToString('yyyyMM_dd')}`) do set "d=%%a"
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims= " %%a in (`%windir%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -command "& {(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().AddHours(-3).ToString('hhmmss')}"`) do set "t=%%a"
echo Zipping.... & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "C:\DFD\JZR_%d%%t%.zip" "C:\DFD\*.txt" & del /q /f /s "C:\DFD*.txt" & echo Done!
```

- Don't overwrite DATE and TIME they are environment variables.
- Used inline powershell to get UTC date and time in your format 3 hours back.

Comment: Thanks Wasif, let me check and udpate you.

Comment: It is zipping the files, but the name is not appearing instead it shows "JZR_"

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to get UTC time is using **WMIC**:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe PATH Win32_UTCTime GET /VALUE') do if not "%%J" == "" set "%%I=%%J"
rem Insert a leading 0 if one of the two digit values has just one digit.
if "%Month:~1%" == "" set "Month=0%Month%"
if "%Day:~1%" == "" set "Day=0%Day%"
if "%Hour:~1%" == "" set "Hour=0%Hour%"
if "%Minute:~1%" == "" set "Minute=0%Minute%"
if "%Second:~1%" == "" set "Second=0%Second%"
rem Use the date/time values in format yyyy-MM-dd_hh_mm_ss in ZIP file name.
"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "C:\DFD\JZR_%Year%-%Month%-%Day%_%Hour%_%Minute%_%Second%.zip" "C:\DFD\*.txt"
endlocal
```

Please run in a command prompt window once `wmic path win32_utctime get /value` to see what **WMIC** outputs in Unicode with UTF-16 LE encoding converted with a quirks by `cmd.exe` to ASCII encoding which requires the **IF** condition. See my answer on [How to remove new lines in batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63109721/3074564) for details about the character encoding conversion problem worked around here with the **IF** condition.

It would be also possible to use as third line:

```
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe PATH Win32_UTCTime GET Day^,Month^,Year^,Hour^,Minute^,Second /VALUE') do if not "%%J" == "" set "%%I=%%J"
```

Then just the six date/time values of interest would be output by **WMIC** whereby character `^` left to each comma is necessary to pass the command line with the commas correct to the command process started in background which executes the **WMIC** command, i.e. to execute in background:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wmic.exe PATH Win32_UTCTime GET Day,Month,Year,Hour,Minute,Second /VALUE
```

The commas would be otherwise interpreted by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file as argument separators inside set of command **FOR** and would replace each `,` by a space character which would make the **WMIC** command invalid.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic path /?`
- `wmic path win32_utctime /?`
- `wmic path win32_utctime get /?`

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed command script and that saved my time and successfully produced the result which I need.  thanks again mofi for the support.